# Verify if a URL exists

Tags: scripting, curl, wget

I would like to verify if a URL exists without downloading. I am using below with `curl`:

```
if [[ $(curl ftp://ftp.somewhere.com/bigfile.gz) ]] 2>/dev/null;
 then
  echo "This page exists."
 else
  echo "This page does not exist."
fi
```

or using `wget`:

```
if [[ $(wget ftp://ftp.somewhere.com/bigfile.gz) -O-]] 2>/dev/null;
 then
  echo "This page exists."
 else
  echo "This page does not exist."
fi
```

This works great if the URL doesn't exist. If it exists, it downloads the file. In my case, the files are really big and I do not want it to download. I just want to know if that URL exists.

Comment: If you are trying to save disk space, try redirecting output of the command to /dev/null.

Comment: See also: [Stack Overflow: How to check if an URL exists with the shell and probably curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12199059/4561887)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're close. The correct way to approach this is using the [HEAD](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#page-25) method.

With cURL:

```
if curl --head --silent --fail ftp://ftp.somewhere.com/bigfile.gz 2> /dev/null;
 then
  echo "This page exists."
 else
  echo "This page does not exist."
fi
```

or using wget:

```
if wget -q --method=HEAD ftp://ftp.somewhere.com/bigfile.gz;
 then
  echo "This page exists."
 else
  echo "This page does not exist."
fi
```

Comment: what version of `wget` did you use for this? I get the error: `wget: unrecognized option '--method=HEAD'`

Comment: `--method=HEAD` was added in Wget 1.15 released over 5 years ago.

Comment: thanks looks like we have version 1.14 on our CentOS 7 server (Build Date: 2016-06-03), that would explain why we dont have this feature

Comment: You could use the `--spider` option in that case.

Answer (score 6):

I think, it is better to use the `--spider` argument with the `wget` tool. It also works on lightweight versions of the `wget` tool (in BusyBox).

Example:

```
URL="http://www.google.com"

if wget --spider "${URL}" 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "OK !"
else
    echo "ERROR ! Online URL ${URL} not found !"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `curl --head`
(HTTP FTP FILE) Fetch the headers only!

```bsh
status=$(curl --head --silent ftp://ftp.somewhere.com/bigfile.gz | head -n 1)

if echo "$status" | grep -q 404
  echo "file does not exist"
else
  echo "file exists"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail "ftp://ftp.somewhere.com/bigfile.gz"
then
  echo "This page exists."
 else
  echo "This page does not exist."
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo $(curl --head --silent <url> | head -n 1)
```